# Place cursor at the last on text box on drop down selection in Kendo UI and Jquery

Tags: jquery, user-interface, kendo-ui, autocomplete

I have a search text box. When you write some text in to this, user is able to see search Suggestion. User can select Multiple search results. When user selects some thing from Search suggestion drop down, The text box value is appended to the text box value.

What I want to achieve is that when the text box content in more than the width of the text box then the cursor should be placed at the last index and also text should be flown to left side and the last key word should be displayed in the text box.

The same fulctionality is done in [Link- search functionality](https://www.naukri.com/)

[search functionality I have to  implement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Kxjm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try calling below function in kendo close event

```
  function setFocus(id) {
        var inputField = document.getElementById(id);
        if (inputField != null && inputField.value.length != 0) {
            if (inputField.createTextRange) {
                var FieldRange = inputField.createTextRange();
                FieldRange.moveStart('character', inputField.value.length);
                FieldRange.collapse();
                FieldRange.select();
            } else if (inputField.selectionStart || inputField.selectionStart == '0') {
                var elemLen = inputField.value.length;
                inputField.selectionStart = elemLen;
                inputField.selectionEnd = elemLen;
                inputField.blur();
                inputField.focus();
            }
        } else {
            inputField.focus();
        }
    }
```

**Kendo Autopopulate code**

```
 @(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete().Name("search")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { @id = "Search", @title = "Search", @placeholder = "SEARCH", @style = "width:277px;padding-right: 25px;" })
                    .MinLength(1)
                    .Separator(",")                    
                    .Events(evt => evt.Close("setFocus('search')"))
```